# OS X System Preferences app don't want to save any changes in Service settings

Tags: macos, service

I'm opening System Preferences app >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Services, and trying to change some options - to set or unset, and no one is enabling or disabling. Even more, after I quit the Preferences app all the options are restoring to their default values

I've tried 'fix permission' option provided by Disk Utility, but it didn't helped

I'm running OS X 10.9.1, but as I remember, this also happened on OS X 10.8.x, but I gave up that time

I've asked my friends, which also run OS X 10.9.1, and they don't have this problem, so it's something specific. Any ideas?

**UPD:** From Guest user, or another account with Admin privileges all is working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that problem is somehow associated with pbs.plist file, where the changes must be saved

So this helped me:

- enter as a guest
- add some changes to the Services
- copy file /Users/Guest/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist to my ~/Library/Preferences folder
- set correct permissions using chown

---

Or you can just save this code to your ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSServicesStatus</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then convert it to binary format

```
plutil -convert binary1 ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist
```

---

Another solution can be to run this command, but I'm not sure, because now all is working, and I can't check it

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs update
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up Terminal (/Programs/Utilities/Terminal.app)
2. Enter "chmod -RN ~/Library/Preferences" (without the quotation marks)
3. Hit return.

via https://discussions.apple.com/message/16715513#16715513

Answer (score 0):

For me removing this file and restarting solved the issue;
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist